# Python - List/Dictionariy

Tags: python

i got a list of dictionaries which I want to plot via matplotlib. Before plotting I need to retrieve the information in ascending order in two lists as integers. Think it’s a pretty basic question, but I couldn’t find the right solutions so far. Can someone help?

```
[
    {'1994': 5}, {'1972': 1}, {'1974': 1}, {'2008': 2}, {'1957': 3},
    {'1993': 1}, {'2003': 2}, {'1966': 1}, {'1999': 4}, {'2001': 3},
    {'1980': 2}, {'2010': 2}, {'2002': 3}, {'1975': 1}, {'1990': 1}, 
    {'1954': 2}, {'1977': 1}, {'1995': 4}, {'1991': 2}, {'1946': 1}, 
    {'1997': 2}, {'1998': 2}, {'2014': 2}, {'1960': 1}, {'1968': 2}, 
    {'1931': 2}, {'1942': 1}, {'2011': 1}, {'1936': 1}, {'2006': 3}, 
    {'1981': 2}, {'1985': 1}, {'2000': 4}, {'1979': 2}, {'1940': 1}, 
    {'1988': 2}, {'1950': 1}, {'1964': 1}, {'2017': 1}, {'2012': 2}, 
    {'1986': 1}, {'1984': 2}, {'1941': 1}, {'1959': 1}, {'1958': 1}, 
    {'1992': 1}, {'1983': 1}, {'2016': 2}, {'2007': 1}, {'1971': 1}, 
    {'1962': 2}, {'2004': 1}, {'1944': 1}, {'1976': 1}, {'1952': 1}, 
    {'2009': 2}, {'1987': 1}, {'1973': 1}, {'1948': 1}, {'1921': 1}
]
```

Finding a good solution

Comment: So, you want the _years_ (i.e., the dictionary keys) to be sorted in ascending order, but keeping their associated value? Or, both the year keys and the values to be sorted independently?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your all numerical which you got from code
and do code

```py
years = [int(list(d.keys())[0]) for d in data]
counts = [list(d.values())[0] for d in data]
```

it extracts years and counts,convert to integer

Based on years

```py
sorted_indices = sorted(range(len(years)), key=lambda k: years[k])
sorted_years = [years[i] for i in sorted_indices]
sorted_counts = [counts[i] for i in sorted_indices]

print(sorted_years)
print(sorted_counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) as a wrapper:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import ChainMap

s = pd.Series(ChainMap(*lst))
s.index = s.index.astype(int)
s.sort_index().plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(myDictArray, key=lambda x: int(list(x.keys())[0]))`